# Protractor debug always enabled how to stop it

Tags: debugging, protractor

Through protractor when tried to execute scripts (through command prompt) .. each line (each script) it is asking press c to continue .. 
To stop this what I need to do..
here is my cmd prompt statements also please suggest how to call this debug function whenever needed.

```
C:\name\pjt Testing\AutomationProt\IO Sample>protractor
(node:11848) DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() i
ead.
[08:49:59] W/driverProviders - Using driver provider directConnect, but also
nd extra driver provider parameter(s): seleniumAddress
[08:49:59] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[08:49:59] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12503/devtools/browser/0472e62f-7d84-463
014-ab0080c3ff0d
Jasmine started
Beforeall Started
 Beforeall ended
[08:50:16] I/protractor -
[08:50:16] I/protractor - Encountered browser.pause(). Attaching debugger...
[08:50:16] I/protractor -
[08:50:16] I/protractor - ------- WebDriver Debugger -------
[08:50:16] I/protractor - Starting WebDriver debugger in a child process. Pau
is still beta, please report issues at github.com/angular/protractor
[08:50:16] I/protractor -
[08:50:16] I/protractor - press c to continue to the next webdriver command
[08:50:16] I/protractor - press ^D to detach debugger and resume code executi
[08:50:16] I/protractor -
Starting debugger agent.
(node:11848) DeprecationWarning: node --debug is deprecated. Please use node
nspect instead.
Debugger listening on 127.0.0.1:10000
>>> c[10996:11420:0201/085204.362:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMEN

[10996:11420:0201/085204.362:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[10996:11420:0201/085204.362:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[10996:11420:0201/085204.363:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[10996:11420:0201/085204.363:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED

c
-- Next command: findElements
>>> -- Next command: findElements
>>> c
-- Next command: clickElement
>>> c
-- Next command: findElements
>>> cf
Unrecognized command.
>>> c
-- Next command: sendKeysToElement
>>>
(To exit, press ^C again or type .exit)
>>> [10996:11420:0201/085404.281:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENT
[10996:11420:0201/085404.281:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[10996:11420:0201/085404.281:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[10996:11420:0201/085404.281:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[10996:11420:0201/085404.281:ERROR:process_metrics.cc(105)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
```

Answer (score 1):

The terminal output that you pasted states that if you want to detach the debugger, you need to press `ctrl-D`:

```
press ^D to detach debugger and resume code execution
```

If you want to avoid starting the debugger altogether, then you need to configure Protractor appropriately, as stated in the [Protractor documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.3.0/lib/config.ts). Here are some relevant options configurable in `conf.js`:

```
  v8Debug?: any;
  nodeDebug?: boolean;
  debuggerServerPort?: number;
  debug?: boolean;
```